# Facebook like button disappears when clicked when adding it dynamically in asp.net web-site?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am making a web-site using asp.net which contains a number of links on the same page. These links are dynamically added from code-behind using asp:panel. I need facebook like button below every link which can like that particular link.
In my aspx file:

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  (function (d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=182176538561221";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_news1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</form>
```

In my aspx.cs file i have:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string linkURL = "http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNHZtva7n5Hd-1W7tGYSwoHLnvc7AA&url=http://zeenews.india.com/news/delhi/bjp-wins-north-delhi-mcd-elections_770339.html";
        Panel_news1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div><a href=\"http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNHZtva7n5Hd-1W7tGYSwoHLnvc7AA&amp;url=http://zeenews.india.com/news/delhi/bjp-wins-north-delhi-mcd-elections_770339.html\"><fb:like href=\""+linkURL+"\" send=\"false\" layout=\"button_count\" width=\"50\" show_faces=\"false\" colorscheme=\"dark\" font=\"trebuchet ms\"></fb:like>"));
    }
```

The problem is that the like button works fine when i put it statically in the aspx file but when i try to get it dynamically or even the linkurl dynamically, the like button disappears when clicked. It is still there but cannot be seen. If clicked again at the same place the confirm pop-up appears and if confirmed the button comes back. 
It is quiet wierd for me as i am unable to get the problem. I tried using IFRAME, HTML5 and XFBML , but the result was the same when adding the button or even the link dynamically.. Please Help...